# Can two consoles play on one online-enabled copy of a game

Tags: ps4, destiny

The wife and I game a lot, and we each have our own PS4. We recently found out the neat option of only one of us needing to have a PS+ account for both of us to basically use it.

If you're reading this and are unfamiliar with how to do this, basically what we did was we made her PS4 my primary one (I have the PS+ account), and she logs in with her profile like normal. My PS4 is set as her primary (I'm not sure if this is necessary or not) but I simply log into my profile as normal and still use my PS+ as normal.

My question here is, if I were to purchase the Destiny bundle with Taken King via digital copy on my profile, and also download the game onto her console, would we both be able to play it at the same time with just the one copy?

Comment: I'm not aware of how Destiny works, but doesn't that game have a separate account that you need to register for? I know that 99% of MMO games work that way.

Comment: Yeah we've both been playing it pretty much since launch, so she's already got all of that set up.

Comment: To clarify: you have a D account, your wife has a D account. You want to buy 1 copy of D+TK, link it to your account, download it onto your wife's machine and then both play the TK expansion?

Comment: I'm not 100% on this, but I have a pretty good hunch you won't be able to play on both at the same time.

Comment: That is correct, Nate. Though, I'm not entirely sure anyone has a Destiny "account", per se? If you do, it's entirely linked into your PS or Xbox Live account.

I'm really hoping that's not the case, two bugs. :(

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Destiny isn't an MMO

Comment: @zuno987, Destiny is not an MMO, but it certainly trys to be. You do have a Destiny account, but put simply, your access to it is limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can play Destiny TTK at the same time, because when you download a digital game onto a different console, it adds a "temp" license for that user, as long as the account that has bought Destiny is on the console the game should be fine.

I hope this helped. Good luck Guardian